# Invoking django tests in subdirectories

Tags: django

I recently split up an app into subdirectories. For example, I had a "shop" app, and I split it up into shop/foo, shop/bar, shop/baz subdirectories, treating each one as a separate app, so my INSTALLED_APPS now looks like:

```
"shop",
"shop.foo",
"shop.bar",
"shop.baz",
...
```

I want to be able to run the tests in shop/foo/tests.py by doing:

```
python manage.py test shop.foo
```

However, if I do that, I get the error:

```
ValueError: Test label 'shop.foo' does not refer to a test
```

On the other hand, I can run the tests by doing this:

```
python manage.py test foo
```

Why is this happening, and what can I change so that I can run the tests as "shop.foo" instead of "foo"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because Django expects the arguments to `test` command to be of the format:

```
app_label[.TestCase[.test_method]]
```

There is no way of doing this with the stock test runner (see, [Carl Meyers comment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17365#comment:6)). If everything goes well, this should be fixed in Django 1.5, but in the meantime you can use an alternate runner which accepts full module paths: [django-discovery-runner](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-discover-runner).

Answer (score 3):

[django-discover-runner](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-discover-runner) has been made part of Django 1.6.. :)

For Version <1.6 , it can be used as a third party app.